# How to put the Output (label) for block diagrams?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am having a hard time to find a way to tikz those block diagrams found in DSP. Realitvely easy one can lay down the Input and some kind of processing block, but i found no way to add a Output to the diagram.

Here is a small example:

[image]

I generated the following tex code, solving it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{blox}
\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \bXInput[$x$]{A}
        \bXBloc[2]{B}{$z^{-1}$}{A}
        \bXOutput[2]{C}{B}
        \bXLink{A}{B}{2}
        \bXLink[$y$]{B}{C}      
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the compiled picture:
[image]

The problem is that i want an output label like i have for the input label and i cant find a good solution in the blox package.

Any ideas how to solve this? Otherwise the blox package looks quite good for the things i want to do.

Comment: Is the `blox` package mandatory? Because this kind of drawing is pretty straightforward in plain Ti*k*Z. Just asking.

Comment: A workaround seem to use `\begin{tikzpicture}[text height=1.3ex]`

Comment: @SebGlav Not so really the bigger the diagrams become. Thats why i would like prefer blox as the overview is much better.

Comment: @vipa i dont see how this will generate me a structure like s(n) --> \box --> y(n)?

Comment: Therefore the problem isn't the misalignment of the labels of the input and output. Correct?

Comment: A not very elegant solution can be to add `\node[anchor=west] at (C) {$y$};` at the end of the code inside the tikzpicture

Comment: yes thats a solution i can live with. Thanks.

Comment: Looking better at the documentation a solution can be: `\begin{tikzpicture}
        \bXInput[$x$]{A}
        \bXBlocL[2]{B}{$z^{-1}$}{A}
  \bXStyleBloc{draw=none}
        \bXBlocL[2]{C}{$y$}{B}
  \bXStyleBlocDefault
    \end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Make a proper answer if it works, not a simple comment ;)